# Expanding to arrow function syntax like for `func`

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In WebStorm when I write `func` and press TAB it's expanded to `function() {}`. I works like `live templates`, but I can't find it in `live templates` section. I have two questions:

1. Where is it defined?
2. Is there something analogues for ES6 arrow functions without the need to define my own template?

Comment: Do you have code completion popup visible when you pressing `TAB`? This most likely is a hard-coded template that is used when you about to complete `function` keyword. Defining custom live template is the easiest solution .. as IDE may not know what kind of function you are willing to use here .. and Live Template will use more determined/precise code.

Comment: Noticed that in [Intellij's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) for live templates, the `func` definition is there, but it's not an option when I check in the IDE itself. @LazyOne is on target here - based on your context func would smart-expand even if it isn't a live template.

Comment: @LazyOne, got it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes I know this is an old post but on the off chance someone is looking, to get the arrow function with emmet installed its just

```
af[TAB]
```

where [TAB] is your IDE's emmet shortcut key

For Atom/ VSC [TAB] is typical

for arrow function ie ()=>{}

For traditional style functions, typically just start typing 'function' and options should appear assuming your IDE is set up for emmet correctly.

Note that whilst in VSC emmet is setup by default, in Atom and Brackets etc you need to add the emmet plug-in.